# Short notation for dependent boolean assignment

Tags: excel, vba

While reviewing the VBA code of someone else, I came across a short notation for a dependent boolean assignment that I've never seen before:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim blnTest As Boolean
    blnTest = Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "No"
    MsgBox blnTest
End Sub
```

The normal version (I used for this kind of use case up until now) would be:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim blnTest As Boolean
    If (Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "No") Then
        blnTest = True
    Else
        blnTest = False
    End If
    MsgBox blnTest
End Sub
```

While both versions seem to do exactly the same, I am wondering whether there are advantages/disadvantages using the one or the other version?

Comment: What are the brackets in the 2nd version good for? IMHO you do not need them. Regarding your uestion I usually prefer the 2nd version becaust it is easier to read. On the other hand the first version ist shortes and in this case clear enough.

Comment: I prefer the first version because a boolean is a boolean: It assigns the result of a boolean test to a boolean variable. However, as VBA (in opposite to most other languages) uses the same operator for a test and a assignment, I find it easier to read to put the test into brackets: `blnTest = (Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "No")`

Comment: @FunThomas: Yes, good reasons to prefer the 1st version.  Anyway, both do the same and in the end it is probably a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! 
@FunThomas: the brackets for the test indeed make it a bit 'clearer' to read - thanks for the hint.